# Destructor on a Array of objects, that were already destructed

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am a bit new to Objects in C++, and I have the following simplified problem:

I want to create an array of objects that are already initialized by the constructer of the class.

Thus:

```
int main() {

 Test A(1);
 Test B(2);
 Test C(3);
 Test TestArray[3]={A,B,C};

 /*
  Code that both uses A,B,C directly and TestArray
 */

 return 0;
}
```

Importantly, the class `Test` dynamically allocates its value. And so the destructor should delete this allocated memory.

Thus:

```
class Test {
    int *PointerToDynMem;
public:
    Test(int);
    ~Test();
};

Test::Test(int a){
    PointerToDynMem=new int(a);
}

Test::~Test(){
    delete PointerToDynMem;
}
```

I think what happens is when the program ends `A`,`B` and `C` go out of scope and call the destructor. But it seems that also when `TestArray` goes out of scope, it also calls the destructor, but `A`,`B`,`C` were already deallocated soo. ERROR.

I always coded like this with normal type objects like an integer, and here it never gave me any problem. It seems that I need to change something, but don't know exactly how, since I want to both us the objects separately and have an array of them.

The thing I am confused about is why the Array should call that destructor, since it is basically a pointer to the first element and so not really an object going out of scope.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: C++ uses value semantics. prefer direct objects over pointers. if you must use a pointer, use a smart-pointer

Comment: Also, many folk say to use _[containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)_ instead of naked arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The thing I am confused about is why the Array should call that destructor, since it is basically a pointer to the first element and so not really an object going out of scope.

An array is **not** a pointer.  If it was, we would just have pointers.  An arrays name can and does decay to a pointer to the first element in the array (which can be really annoying) but it isn't a pointer.  It is an object that stores `N` objects in a contiguous piece of memory and that size information is part of it's type.  That means a `int[5]` is not the same type as a `int[6]`.

What happens here is

```
Test TestArray[3]={A,B,C};
```

creates an array of three `Test` and then copy initializes each `Test` object in the array from the initializers `{A,B,C}`.  So when `main` ends, `TestArray` is destroyed call the destructor for each element.  And then `C`, `B` and `A` as destroyed in that order.

This is a problem for you though since you class just uses the default copy constructor.  That means each object in the array has a copy of the point of the object it was initialized by and it points to the same memory.  So when the array gets destroyed, `delete` is called on all of the member pointers and then `C`, `B` and `A` try to delete that same memory again, which is undefined behavior.

What you need to do is follow the [rule rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) and create the special member functions so your class is copied correctly, or you can use RAII in the form of smart pointers/`std::vector` and let them handle all of that for you and you can use the [rule of zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation on what happens when the TestArray is created. I didn't know what happend in the background. I will definitely read it through on what the different rules mean.

Answer (score 4):

`TestArray[3]={A,B,C};` will copy the `int*` held by A, B and C using the default copy constructor. To remedy this, create all constructors and operators that would otherwise be silently created for you. Read [the rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

```
class Test {
    int *PointerToDynMem;
public:
    Test(int);
    Test(const Test&);            // implement this
    Test(Test&&);                 // implement this
    Test& operator=(const Test&); // implement this
    Test& operator=(Test&&);      // implement this
    ~Test();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

For that code you need to add a copy constructor (and also operator= etc for a 'real' code)

```
Test::Test(const Test & t) {
  PointerToDynMem=new int(*t.PointerToDynMem);
}
```

else your `int*` is shared (`TestArray[0].PointerToDynMem` is `A.PointerToDynMem` and `TestArray[1].PointerToDynMem` is `B.PointerToDynMem` and `TestArray[2].PointerToDynMem` is `C.PointerToDynMem`) and deleted 2 times